# How to get dataset into array

Tags: csv, numpy, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I have worked all the tutorials and searched for "load csv tensorflow" but just can't get the logic of it all. I'm not a total beginner, but I don't have much time to complete this, and I've been suddenly thrown into Tensorflow, which is unexpectedly difficult.

Let me lay it out:

Very simple CSV file of 184 columns that are all float numbers. A row is simply today's price, three buy signals, and the previous 180 days prices

```
close = tf.placeholder(float, name='close')

signals = tf.placeholder(bool, shape=[3], name='signals')

previous = tf.placeholder(float, shape=[180], name = 'previous')
```

This article: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets
It covers how to load pretty well. It even has a section on changing to numpy arrays, which is what I need to train and test the 'net. However, as the author says in the article leading to this Web page, it is pretty complex. It seems like everything is geared toward doing data manipulation, where we have already normalized our data (nothing has really changed in AI since 1983 in terms of inputs, outputs, and layers).

Here is a way to load it, but not in to Numpy and no example of not manipulating the data.

```
 with tf.Session as sess:

  sess.run( tf.global variables initializer())

  with open('/BTC1.csv') as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter =',')

    line_count = 0

    for row in csv_reader:

      ?????????

      line_count += 1
```

I need to know how to get the csv file in to the

```
close = tf.placeholder(float, name='close')

signals = tf.placeholder(bool, shape=[3], name='signals')

previous = tf.placeholder(float, shape=[180], name = 'previous')
```

so that I can follow the tutorials to train and test the net.

Comment: A somewhat humorous question in an otherwise 'tense' forum.

Comment: Is [this](https://databricks.com/tensorflow/basic-reading-with-python-code) helpful ?

Comment: Ah... I didn't notice they used a CSV. We old people... Sheesh =)

Answer (score 0):

It's not that clear for me your question. You might be answering, tell me if I'm wrong, how to feed data in your model? There are several fashions to do so.

1. Use placeholders with `feed_dict` during the session. This is the basic and easier one but often suffers from training performance issue. Further explanation, check this [post](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets).
2. Use queue. Hard to implement and badly documented, I don't suggest, because it's been taken over by the third method.
3. `tf.data` API.

...

So to answer your question **by the first method**:

```
# get your array outside the session
with open('/BTC1.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter =',')
    dataset = np.asarray([data for data in csv_reader])
    close_col = dataset[:, 0]
    signal_cols = dataset[:, 1: 3]
    previous_cols = dataset[:, 3:]

# let's say you load 100 row each time for training
batch_size = 100

# define placeholders like you
...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    ...
    for i in range(number_iter):
        start = i * batch_size
        end = (i + 1) * batch_size
        sess.run(train_operation, feed_dict={close: close_col[start: end, ],
                                             signals: signal_col[start: end, ],
                                             previous: previous_col[start: end, ]
                                             }
                 )
```

**By the third method**:

```
# retrieve your columns like before
...

# let's say you load 100 row each time for training
batch_size = 100

# construct your input pipeline
c_col, s_col, p_col = wrapper(filename)
batch = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((close_col, signal_col, previous_col))
batch = batch.shuffle(c_col.shape[0]).batch(batch_size)  #mix data --> assemble batches --> prefetch to RAM and ready inject to model
iterator = batch.make_initializable_iterator()
iter_init_operation = iterator.initializer
c_it, s_it, p_it = iterator.get_next() #get next batch operation automatically called at each iteration within the session

# replace your close, signal, previous placeholder in your model by c_it, s_it, p_it when you define your model
...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # you need to initialize the iterators
    sess.run([tf.global_variable_initializer, iter_init_operation])
    ...
    for i in range(number_iter):
        start = i * batch_size
        end = (i + 1) * batch_size
        sess.run(train_operation)
```

Good luck!